# How to make column bold in array?

Tags: math-mode, bold, arrays, boldmath

```
\begin{align*}
    \begin{array}{cc|>{\boldsymbol}cclccl}
        X&Y&\neg&X&\rightarrow(&Y&\rightarrow&X))\\
        \hline
        0&0&0&0&1&0&1&0\\
        0&1&0&0&1&1&0&0\\
        1&0&0&1&1&0&1&1\\
        1&1&0&1&1&1&1&1
    \end{array}
\end{align*}
```

I just need the first column right to the vertical line to be bold. I couldn't figure out how to make this work; I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`collcell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) seems to help here, passing the cell contents to a `\user` `macro` (with one argument) via the [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array)-like column specification

```
. . . >{\collectcell\usermacro}c<{\endcollectcell} . . .
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,collcell}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{ c c | >{\collectcell\boldsymbol}c<{\endcollectcell} c l c c l }
    X & Y & \neg & X & \rightarrow( & Y & \rightarrow & X)) \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility, without `collcell`, is to use a short definition like this:

```
\def\bstart#1\bstop{\boldsymbol{#1}}
```

This way, you will be able to bypass the `&` character at the end of each cell of the array and get the required bold math symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\def\bstart#1\bstop{\boldsymbol{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{ c c | >{\bstart} c <{\bstop} c l c c l }
    X & Y & \neg & X & \rightarrow( & Y & \rightarrow & X)) \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Enable `\boldmath`, but for this we need to exit from math mode, issuing `\boldmath` and reentering math mode. This is more conveniently done with a new column type.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\boldmath$}c}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{ c c | C c l c c l }
    X & Y & \neg & X & \rightarrow( & Y & \rightarrow & X)) \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
   \begin{document}


   \huge
   \begin{tabular}{cc|cccccc}    
   X&Y&${\bf\neg}$&X&$\rightarrow$&Y&$\rightarrow$&X\\        \hline
    0&0&{\bf 0}&0&1&0&1&0\\
    0&1&{\bf 0}&0&1&1&0&0\\
    1&0&{\bf 0}&1&1&0&1&1\\
    1&1&{\bf 0}&1&1&1&1&1\\\hline    
    \end{tabular}

    \end{document}
```

% This is a simple way of preparing the table.

Comment: you might want to read http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-2letterfontcmd.html